# SQL Maintenance Plan - End Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, maintenance-plan

Is there any way to stop a maintenance plan after it has been triggered? I have one that is running in Production and need to stop is ASAP.

Appreciate any suggestions/ideas. Thanks!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming SSIS w/ SQL Server, "SQL Server Agent" -> "Job Activity Monitor".  Right-click the job that you don't want running and select "Stop Job"

This could be worse than letting the job run.  Be warned.